# Does QML support converting to different timezone based on timezoneID?

Tags: qt, datetime, qml, timezone-offset

I am making a world clock QML program. I am currently using an API to get the timezone ID of a certain city.

So for instance, for Delft, it would return

```
TimezoneID = Europe/Amsterdam
```

I store the city name and its timezoneID in a local sql database so that I wouldn't have to keep parsing online for the timezone info.

In my application, I have a ListView which displays the cityname along side its local time. **How do I calculate the time at Delft using my system time and its timezoneID?**

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, QML itself does not have this functionality, here are alternatives:

Since you already use a database, why don't you simply add the [zone.tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab) part of the [tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to your database and calculate the times yourself? (Don't forget about daylight saving time...)

If you don't like that, you can also use [TimezoneJS](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js), a javascript library for handling timezones (which needs a copy of the same database mentioned above).

Or you write a C++ plugin for QML that encapsulates`date` and `tzset`.

Comment: I would love to use the first suggestions (zone.tab), however how can I know when to apply daylight saving time and when not to? Countries change from DST to Normal at different dates. The second method does not have this limitation, however I am not really leaning towards it due to the large javascript library that I need to include. I am hesitant because javascript reduces performance amongst other reasons in QML.

Comment: Zone.tab is supplemental info.  The info needed for DST calculation is the bulk of the TZDB.  @Nik - I don't know anything about QML, but if you can run javascript like Xubuntix suggested, there are several different libraries to choose from.  I list them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Comment: If you're going the C++ route, you might look into using Boost, which supports the IANA style timezones (like `Europe/Amsterdam`).  You can read more [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html)